# Drupal Secondary Links Front Page Issue

Tags: drupal, drop-down-menu, hyperlink, drupal-theming, frontpage

I'm trying to get my secondary links (which are using primary links as the source, so the children of the primary links) to display as a dropdown on every page.  However, since (im guessing) there is no active trail on the front page, the secondary links aren't displayed.

How do I set them so that I can display the secondary links on the front page?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display secondary links only on frontpage, don't forget to add an *if* statement such as:

```
if ($is_front) {
    print theme('links',$secondary_links,array('class' => 'class-for-secondary-links'));
}
```

Or just use custom template for frontpage.

Comment: That would probably be my preferred approach -- I assume you're talking about modifying the page template page.tpl.php?  Menu Block module would probably work (Matt V's answer) but I feel installing a custom module for a piece of functionality you'll use in just one place is an inefficient solution that complicates your site.

Comment: Put it just where you want. If your main template file is page.tpl.php - put it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "theme" function to display the secondary links into your front page:

```
 print theme('links', $secondary_links, array('class' => 'links secondary-links'));
```

And to create the dropdown you can overwrite the "theme_links" function into your template.php file: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_links

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module will do what you're describing and a whole lot more.